# To Kill an Observable

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, reactivex, rx-kotlin

Excuse the pun, had to do it to em.

I have an observable that is declared like so:

```
Observable
        .interval(20, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .subscribe {
            val timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - testSum
            Log.i("LOG", "TIME DIFF: $timeDiff")
            testSum = System.currentTimeMillis()

            mVisualizer.getWaveForm(waveformByteArray)
            onWaveFormDataCaptureManual(waveformByteArray)
        }
```

And no matter what I try to do, this observable will not die. disposables.add() (which seems to be the answer in Java) gives me an unresolved reference error. Before that, I can't even save it to a variable either, as that also shows a lot of red on the screen.

FYI I've Googled this problem. Nothing works.

Comment: do you use Rxjava 2 or 3?

Comment: RxJava 2. But Manohar's solution is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take the output disposable and dispose it

```
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable  //required import

 var diposable:Disposable?=null   //global variable


   disposable= Observable
            .interval(20, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribe {
                val timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - testSum
                Log.i("LOG", "TIME DIFF: $timeDiff")
                testSum = System.currentTimeMillis()

                mVisualizer.getWaveForm(waveformByteArray)
                onWaveFormDataCaptureManual(waveformByteArray)
            }
```

to dispose use

```
 disposable?.dispose()
```

If you have multiple disposables then you can use `CompositeDisposable`

```
 var compositeDisposable:CompositeDisposable= CompositeDisposable()

 val disposable= Observable
        .interval(20, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .subscribe {
            val timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - testSum
            Log.i("LOG", "TIME DIFF: $timeDiff")
            testSum = System.currentTimeMillis()

            mVisualizer.getWaveForm(waveformByteArray)
            onWaveFormDataCaptureManual(waveformByteArray)
        }

     compositeDisposable.add(disposable)
    // you can add as many disposables as you want
```

to Dispose use

```
   compositeDisposable.dispose()  //every thing is disposed
```